# comment files and s

Tags: comments, templates

I am building a custom template and would like to incorporate comments and replies using the standard WordPress core.  What files and scripts do  I need? I copied a comments.php file but the replies aren't working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would also suggest to have a look at the default themes how they incorporate comments. The default themes are always a great place to start if you need info on such things. They are there, use them.

Comment: Thanks. What I really needed is Otto's reference below. I had already looked in the default themes without understanding how the reply code worked.

Comment: Just glad you anyone could be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ottopress.com/2008/wordpress-2-7-comments-enhancements/

You can ignore the references to legacy stuff. That was posted 6 years ago, we're past the need for pre 2.7 support.